# How can I do folder to require SSL certificate by IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, ssl-certificate

I have to make a WCF service in visual studio 2015 MVC and it needs to be accesible only by SSL certificate, I´m using IIS (in Windows10) and trying to limit SSL for only this service (stored in a specifc folder).

When I change IIS option of this folder to "require SSL" the service said that "the http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'"

I changed web.config too, maybe something is bad there, the service´s name is EncServiceSSL

How can I do it?

WEB.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="ServiceCredentialsBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
             <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyNamespace.ClientCertificateValidator, MyAssembly">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="MyNamespace.AdamAuthorizationPolicy, MyAssembly" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
            </serviceAuthorization>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="1234xx" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"   storeLocation="LocalMachine"  storeName="Root"/>
               <clientCertificate>
                   <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"  trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>  
           <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="https" port="443"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>



      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialsBehavior"  name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8111/ServicesSSL/EncServiceSSL"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="QuoteService"
                  name="SecuredByClientCertificate"
                  contract="encelogistica.QuoteServiceReference.QuoteServiceSoapChannel" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="QuoteService">         
          <security mode="Transport">               
                   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />            
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="QuoteServiceSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
    <client>

      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8111/ServicesSSL/EncServiceSSL.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QuoteServiceSoap"
        contract="QuoteServiceReference.QuoteServiceSoap" name="QuoteServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl

Comment: Thanks, I did this but  when I try to go to the service is already it gives to me the error: " "the http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'"

Comment: then that’s another question.